# I am trying to scrape images from a website with playwright. I am unable to scrape its one div content load dynamically

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I totally don't get the page load normally, still, bigImage is empty.
Here's the below code.
I am using **asyncio** and **playwright** along with lxlm and requests.
I am trying to wait for the element to load but the element has loaded
but does not reflect in the code.

Here's the Github repo link:  [github.com/OAtulA/Flipkart-AmazonImageDownloader/tree/edits](https://%20github.com/OAtulA/Flipkart-AmazonImageDownloader/tree/edits)

***Inputfile***

```
Products File:
Products.txt

Image Output Folder:
Product-Images
```

***Products.txt***

```
black sneakers, https://www.flipkart.com/atom-sneakers-men/p/itm74ce4c7c2d4b9?pid=SHOGHYV8GPF2HNEC&lid=LSTSHOGHYV8GPF2HNECKHMMST&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=jordan+shoes&store=osp%2Fcil%2Fe1f&srno=s_1_11&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&fm=search-autosuggest&iid=en_FhuSro4-26x7lsgKP6XuQPlbRWXb4hVzCcG4YmqgaBgP8HcROpRwPq2TKJFuvdHoVe-6n18rUHThOVLpsiCapA%3D%3D&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&ssid=fi2iod6weznugg741695385201496&qH=57e1b9f14a605a5e
Series 7 sneakers, https://www.flipkart.com/kraasa-series-7-sneakers-men/p/itmda307099c343b?pid=SHOGF3MZZGBFJAEK&lid=LSTSHOGF3MZZGBFJAEK9XAYQP&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=jordan+shoes&store=osp%2Fcil%2Fe1f&srno=s_1_27&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&fm=search-autosuggest&iid=en_FhuSro4-26x7lsgKP6XuQPlbRWXb4hVzCcG4YmqgaBh2G1kDBg4cDrsZtr5_NM9Ybc6ftsImCKTMyJb1-owaSw%3D%3D&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&qH=57e1b9f14a605a5e
red shoes, https://www.flipkart.com/bescettro-shoes-white-stylish-jordan-light-weight-mens-casual-sport-trending-gym-outdoor-casuals-men/p/itm9acb33113c4e0?pid=SHOGE5U7GXATDPDN&lid=LSTSHOGE5U7GXATDPDNOJOTHL&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=jordan+shoes&store=osp%2Fcil%2Fe1f&srno=s_1_19&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&fm=search-autosuggest&iid=a3973867-33b5-4b7c-8a7d-b6fe6db70759.SHOGE5U7GXATDPDN.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&qH=57e1b9f14a605a5e
```

It's safe to assume that installation is proper and the code before the

```py
# Wait for the element with class "_3li7GG" to become visible
        await page.wait_for_selector("_3li7GG", state="visible")

        await page.wait_for_selector("_1BweBB")
```

The program starts here

```py
from lxml import html
import os
import requests
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

# This is literally going to download the pics
def downLoading(product, images, bigImage, Pic_name, url, OutputLocation):

    # This code is mainly going to grab the image
    image_count = 1
    # So that even if we have multiple images for
    # same product we can easily choose.    

    bigImageLink = bigImage.xpath('@src')[0]

    if product.strip() != '':
        for image in images:
            name = Pic_name + " " + str(image_count)
            image_count += 1
            # to get all the images of a product

            # link = image['src']
            link = image.xpath('@src')[0]
            

            # Link looks like this 
            '''
            # 1st small image 
            # src="https://rukminim2.flixcart.com/image/128/128/xif0q/shoe/l/t/l/8-rkt-19039-black-42-atom-black-original-imagzmhf7d8fgd38.jpeg?q=70"

            # 1st big image 
            # src="https://rukminim2.flixcart.com/image/832/832/xif0q/shoe/l/t/l/8-rkt-19039-black-42-atom-black-original-imagzmhf7d8fgd38.jpeg?q=70"
            '''

               # Now setting the link to get the big images for flipkart
            if 'flipkart' in url:
                # Now I get the smallImage dimesions as well as big images dimensions.
                start_index = link.find("image/") + len("image/")
                end_index = start_index + 7
                smallDimension = link[start_index:end_index]

                start_index = bigImageLink.find("image/") + len("image/")
                end_index = start_index + 7
                bigDimension = bigImageLink[start_index:end_index]
                
                link = link.replace(smallDimension, bigDimension)
                # Not needed now.
                # link = link.replace('q=70', 'q=50')

            name = name.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '') + '.jpg'
            name = OutputLocation + '/' + name
            # To get the file in the desired location

            with open(name, 'wb') as photo:
                im = requests.get(link)
                photo.write(im.content)
                # Writing the downloaded file.
                print('Writing: ', name)



def download_image(name, link, OutputLocation):

    name = name.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '') + '.jpg'
    name = os.path.join(OutputLocation, name)
    with open(name, 'wb') as photo:
        im = requests.get(link)
        photo.write(im.content)
        print('Writing:', name)

async def scrape_website(product, url, Pic_name, OutputLocation):
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(url)

        # Wait for the element with class "_35DpL- _2_B7hD" to become visible
        await page.wait_for_selector("_3li7GG", state="visible")

        await page.wait_for_selector("_1BweBB")

        # Get the HTML content after waiting for the element
        html_content = await page.content()

        # You can now parse the HTML content using lxml and extract the images
        html_tree = html.fromstring(html_content)
        images = html_tree.xpath("//ul[@class='_3GnUWp']/li/div/div/img")
        bigImage = html_tree.xpath("//div[@class='_1BweB8']//img")

        # Download images as before
        # download_image(Pic_name, bigImage[0].xpath('@src')[0], OutputLocation)
        downLoading(product= product, images= images, bigImage= bigImage, Pic_name= Pic_name, url= url, OutputLocation= OutputLocation)        

        await browser.close()

        

async def img_graber(products, OutputLocation):
    for product in products:
        Pic_name, link = product.split(',')
        Pic_name = Pic_name.strip()
        link = link.strip()
        url = link

        if 'flipkart' in url:
            await scrape_website(product, url, Pic_name, OutputLocation)
        # You can add support for other websites as needed.

def Inputs():
    file = open('Inputfile', 'r')

    InputLines = []
    temp_inputLines = file.readlines()

    for line in temp_inputLines:
        if line != '\n':
            InputLines.append(line.strip('\n'))

    for i in range(len(InputLines)):
        if "Products File:" in InputLines[i]:
            productsInfo = open(InputLines[i+1], 'r')
            products = productsInfo.readlines()
            productsInfo.close()
        elif "Image Output Folder:" in InputLines[i]:
            OutputLocation = InputLines[i+1]
            try:
                os.makedirs(OutputLocation)
            except:
                pass

    temp_products = products
    products = []

    for p in temp_products:
        p = p.strip('\n')

        if p != '':
            products.append(p)

    asyncio.run(img_graber(products=products, OutputLocation=OutputLocation))
    file.close()

Inputs()
```

***Thanks in Advance humble developer.***

Comment: Well you can see the complete code here Thanks @ggorlen https://github.com/OAtulA/Flipkart-AmazonImageDownloader/tree/edits